# how to separate login for admin and user? c++

Tags: c++

How to compare the username and password entered by user with the data(username and password saved in before) in the admin array and customer array,

so for example when it match the username and password in the admin array, it will directs the user to the admin_mainmenu(), otherwise it directs to the customer_mainmenu().

help please..

```
char username_admin[10];
char password_admin[10];

string username_customer[50];
string password_customer[50];


int main(){
fstream login("password.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::in);  // will not create file
if (login.is_open())
{
    cout << "Database exists." << endl;
    admin_signin();
}
else
{
    cout << "Database Do not exits. Be an adminstrator. Sign Up";
    admin_signup();
    login.clear();
    login.open("password.txt", ios_base::out);  // will create if necessary
}

    admin/customer_mainmenu();


    system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed your post to actually have the code in a code block, but you should format it properly. Many of the lines of code are on a single line.

Comment: Use a real database and add a role property/field. Store passwords as hashes + salt.

Comment: @JosephMansfield thank you joseph, I don't know how to make it inside a code block in this forum, my actual code is not on a single line.

Comment: @Paranaix can you be more specific, maybe show me some codes, because I'm new in c++..

Comment: I doubt you know what `string username_customer[50]` means. What does it means?

Comment: it's an array I made for storing customer's username.
correct me if i'm wrong. @Jefffrey